# postgres select by date (long) with timezone

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

This query gives duplicates however I am struggling to understand exactly why? I do have many rows per id in trading.delayed but only one with the exact same timestamp

Could someone explain me what I am missing ?

```
      SELECT t1.contract,t1.date FROM trading.delayed AS t1, 
(SELECT contract, max(date) AS date FROM trading.delayed GROUP BY contract) AS t2 
WHERE t1.date =t2.date order BY contract DESC;
```

Results: contract, date

```
32;"2017-06-07 02:04:11.797+07"
32;"2017-06-07 02:04:14.489+07"
31;"2017-06-07 02:04:12.04+07"
30;"2017-06-07 02:03:54.182+07"
30;"2017-06-07 00:20:27.812+07"
30;"2017-06-07 02:03:51.177+07"
29;"2017-06-07 00:20:27.812+07"
28;"2017-06-07 01:45:53.129+07"
27;"2017-06-07 01:58:02.974+07"
```

Comment: running the exact query on id (not contract id) works though. Seems like a behaviour with date which is a timestamp by the way.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but this version works

```
SELECT t1.contract,close 
FROM trading.delayed AS t1, 
    ( 
      SELECT max(id) as id, 
             contract, 
             max(date) AS date 
      FROM trading.delayed 
      GROUP BY contract
   ) AS t2 
WHERE t1.id =t2.id 
order by contract desc;
```

---